# Replacing a character in a list

Tags: python-3.x

Im making a hangman game and the first function to make is an function that recieves a word, pattern (_ _ _ _ _) and a letter, and then add the letter to the pattern according to the index of the letter in the word.

for some reason - this code is not working. I'v tried to run it and the loop works well for 3 times till letter = index_1 and then it collapse

can you sopt  the problem?

```
word = 'hallo'
i = 0
index_1 = word[i]
letter = 'l'
ling = len(word)
pattern = ['_']*ling
if letter in word:
   for i in range(ling):
      index_1 = word[i]
      if letter == index_1:
         pattern[index_1] = letter
```

Comment: *and then it collapse* is not a useful problem description. How **specifically** does it not work?

Comment: The last line should be `pattern[i] = letter` as you're trying to index into the array. `index_1 == 'l'` which isn't a valid index for a list.